# Retornar una promesa que contiene un array con datos provenientes de otras promesas

Tags: nodejs, express, promesas

Estoy armando una función en expresJS que utilizando dos funciones simples ejecute dos consultas SQL usando Knex a dos bases de datos distintas, pero debe retornar como respuesta una promesa.

```
function qDB1(status_id) {
  return KnexDB1
  .select()
  .from('table1')
  .where({
    status: status_id
  })
  .orderBy('date')
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

function qDB2 () {
  var dateStart=Moment().format('L');
  var dateEnd=Moment().add(1, 'days').format('L');
  return KnexImc
  .raw("EXEC SP_DB2 'QU', '"+dateStart+"','"+dateEnd+"'")
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

QueryRepo.prototype.select = function(status_id) {

  if ( !status_id) {
    status_id=1;
  }
  var results = [];

  qDB1(status_id)
  .then(function (res) {
    for(var idx = 0; idx < res.length; idx++){
      console.log(res[idx]);
      results.push(res[idx]);
    }
  });
  qDB2()
  .then(function (res) {
    for(var idx2 = 0; idx2 < res.length; idx2++){
      console.log(res[idx2]);
      results.push(res[idx2]);
    }
  });

  return Promise.all(results);

};
```

Cuando ejecuto las funciones `qDB1` y `qDB2` funcionan bien y cargan los datos en `results`, el problema es que al ejecutar `select` la promesa llega como un array vacío.

Sé que podría devolver el array `resuls` una vez que se completaron las promesas de Knex, pero es necesario que la respuesta sea una promesa.

Comment: debe ser algun tipo de asincronidad, prueba con `setTimeout` en algun lado, pone el `setTimeout` antes de: `if ( !status_id) {` y terminalo antes del `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando mal el `Promise.all`. Te recomiendo mirar cómo funciona [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa/all). Básicamente el `Promise.all` recibe como parámetro promises. Si te fijás bien, en `select` deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
return Promise.all([qDB1(status_id), qDB2()]).then(function(values){
    // Merge the two query results
    var promiseResults = values[0].concat(values[1]);

    var results;

    for(var idx = 0; idx < promiseResults.length; idx++){
        results.push(promiseResults[idx]);
    }
    // Returns a promise with the results
    return Promise.resolve(results);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

- Saca el catch de `qDB1` y `qDB2`.

Esto devolvería una `promise`. Por ende cuando llames a `select` deberías usar:

```
select().then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta funciono a la perfeccion.